# Flutter Wrap widget inside Row widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to achieve this behavior. I have 4 items in a Row but I want two texts in the middle act like the yare in a Wrap widget and `text2`  moves to next line if `text1` is long and fill all spaces.
[image]

Here is my code but it overflows instead of wrapping texts in two lines

```
  Widget _buildItem(String name, String status) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimens.unitX2),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: Dimens.unitX5,
            height: Dimens.unitX5,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: Dimens.unitX1),
          Wrap(
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
            alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
            spacing: Dimens.unitX1,
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Text(name),
              Text(status),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(width: Dimens.unitX1),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: Dimens.unitX5,
            height: Dimens.unitX5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap the `Wrap` widget in a `Flexible`:

```
...
Flexible(
    child: Wrap(
       crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
       alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
       spacing: 30,
       direction: Axis.horizontal,
       children: [
       Text('Text1'),
       Text('Text2 is a long text'),
     ],
   ),
 ),
...
```

Answer (score 7):

wrap your `Wrap` Widget with `Expanded` widget :

```dart
Widget _buildItem(String name, String status) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimens.unitX2),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    width: Dimens.unitX5,
                    height: Dimens.unitX5,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: Dimens.unitX1),
                Expanded(
                    child: Wrap(
                        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        spacing: Dimens.unitX1,
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: [
                            Text(name),
                            Text(status),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: Dimens.unitX1),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: Dimens.unitX5,
                    height: Dimens.unitX5,
                ),
            ],
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting with both `Flexible` and `Expanded`. They both work, i.e. long `Row` wrapped.

But in case `Row` is short they work differently - `Expanded` takes all available space, but `Flexible` is not.

`Flexible` on the left, `Expanded` on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Wrap(
   alignment : WrapAlignment.spaceBetween
)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using it in my code